# Failed to load control 'VSFlexGrid' from vsflex8.ocx

Tags: vb6

I have a problem when I compile my program and run it on another computer.

The problem is:

```
Run-time error '372';

Failed to load control 'VSFlexGrid' from vsflex8.ocx. your version of vsflex8.ocx may be outdated. Make sure you are using the version of the control that was provided with your application
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that an older version of that file is registered with Windows, even though the older file may no longer be on the machine.

**Method 1** : Register this version of OCX file by :

1. Go to your windows start menu and select run.
2. Enter REGSVR32 filename.ocx like :

   **Windows 32Bits** :  `regsvr32 C:\Windows\System32\vsflex8.ocx`

   **Windows 64Bits** :  `regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vsflex8.ocx`
3. Click OK

[image]

**Method 2** : use command prompt

1. Right click on Command Prompt and **run as administrator**.
2. Now try registering the dll file and you should be able to do it.

[image]

Remark : there is many way to open an Elevated Command Prompt in Windows 10.

- Open Elevated Command Prompt from Win+X Quick Link Menu

[image]

- Open Elevated Command Prompt from Task Manager
- Open Elevated Command Prompt by Searching Start Menu

> You must run the command prompt in administrator mode (**run as
>   administrator**)

Comment: @rudyasrian Try : `regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vsflex8.ocx`

Comment: the module "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vsflex8.ocx" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x8002801c,

Comment: @rudyasrian This error message happens if you’re not executing the commands under elevated (administrator), you can use method 2 in answer to register ocx.